# Bounding on the Lagrange's Remainder

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I was studying Taylor's Polynomials and Lagrange's Error Bound when this doubt struck me.

From what I understood it is given by max|f^(n+1)(z)| * (x-a)^(n+1)/(n+1)! and z is contained on the interval from a to x(considering x>a).

Whenever I checked solved exercises when f^(n+1) was equal to sin(z) the max would always be setup to 1, why? E.g on khan academy he was approximating for sin(0.4) so in that case z would be contained on the following interval [0;0.4] so why isn't the max sin(0.4) instead of sin(pi/2)?

But when doing the same thing for e^x, x would be rounded to the nearest integer. E.g Sal was calculating for e^1.45 so he defined the max has e^2.

I know I'm comparing two different functions, one goes to infinity while the other is bounded but still. Would my approach be correct?

Here's another example of what I'm describing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9y43_02vFw

At 11:03 the guy clearly says z is between 0 and 0.1 but proceeds to write 0 < sin(z) < 1. I can understand it's indeed correct but isn't that just increasing the error even more? If I wrote sin(0.1) would it be wrong?

Comment: your post is not readable

Comment: @daulomb sorry, what do you mean? If you're talking about the math expression I don't know how to display them in a better way :/ Could you provice some docs?

Comment: I'm guessing that @daulomb meant that you need to use more commas, more periods, and more coherence. A little LaTeX might help too. But by the time I was done reading, I felt breathelss, as if I'd been on a roller-coaster ride, but no wiser about what you were actually asking. So: aim for complete sentences. Pose clearly stated questions. Form paragraphs in which the first sentence introduces the remainder of the sentences. And for Pete's sake, don't send us off to watch some video. There are lots of questions we can choose to answer; make *yours* one of the ones that's worth the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct, and will give you a better bound on the error.

One reason why one might choose $1$ instead of $\sin(0.4)$ is for clarity, as we don't know an exact value for $\sin(0.4)$. Another reason is to get a global bound for $\sin(x)$. You would know the error for every $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The lagrange' expression for error is:

$\frac{f^{(n)}(\zeta)}{n!}(\zeta-x_0)^n$

This means only that these formula is bounded from $\max{f^{(n)}}$, without meaning that it is the error. In the example you used, the error is, in fact $\sin(0.4)$, which is in fact bounded by your expression